# Setting Up Backstage with Guest Authentication on a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: backstage, k8s-serviceaccount

I'm working on deploying Backstage on a Kubernetes cluster using the Helm chart and looking to enable guest user access for development purposes. However, I'm encountering a "501 Not Implemented" error when accessing the `/api/auth/guest/refresh` endpoint. I've configured the guest provider in both my `App.tsx` for the frontend and in the `app-config.yaml` for the backend. The cluster is accessible internally, and I'm using HAProxy for ingress routing to access Backstage externally.

**Installation & Configuration Details:**

- **Installation Method**: Deployed Backstage using the Helm chart provided in the official repository.
- **Access Method**: Accessing the Backstage UI via HAProxy, which is configured to route external requests to my Kubernetes cluster.
- **Cluster Access**: The cluster is configured for internal access, with necessary network policies in place to secure it.
- **Guest User Setup**:

  - *Frontend*: Added `guest` to the providers array in the `SignInPage` component within `App.tsx`.
  - *Backend*: Included `auth.providers.guest: {}` in my `app-config.yaml`.

Despite following the setup instructions, the guest authentication isn't working as expected due to the "501 Not Implemented" error. Has anyone successfully set up guest user access in a similar environment, or does anyone have insights on troubleshooting this issue within a Kubernetes deployment accessed through HAProxy?

Any advice, insights, or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!